# Signal of Signals ? Reactive Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I am trying to understand this piece of code and why it returns a signal of signals.

```
[[[self.signInButton
   rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
   map:^id(id x) {
     return [self signInSignal];
   }]
   subscribeNext:^(id x) {
     NSLog(@"Sign in result: %@", x);
   }];
```

From what I understand the UIControlEventTouchupInside returns a next signal which contains the UIButton when unwrapped in the map function.

So from this, is it safe to conclude that when I perform the map, it expects that the object returned is an object (which happens to be a signal) and it double wraps the signal into a signal. That is reactive cocoa usually expects the type to be a object type and wrap's it into a signal  ?

Or

Am I missing something here, and my understanding of Map is not as follows,
It transforms the input value, and produces an output value, (independent of the input value sometimes)

Thanks I am new to this any advice would be nice!

Another related question,

Lets just say that uicontrol event touch up inside sends and error event, would it be caught by the subscribe next error ?

Comment: Its a good tutorial to understand [ReactiveCocoa](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62699/reactivecocoa-tutorial-pt1)

Comment: That is where I obtained the code from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code looks incorrect. You are correct in understanding that the code takes the signal of button taps and maps it to a signal of "sign-in signals". Yes, a signal of signals. While a signal of signals is common and very useful, it will do nothing without the use of one of these three operators: `flatten`, `concat` or `switchToLatest`. In the given code, `signInSignal` will never be triggered because none of these operators are used.

If you switch `map:` to `flattenMap:`, the sign-in signal will be properly started.

```
[[[self.signInButton
    rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
    flattenMap:^id(id x) {
        return [self signInSignal];
    }]
    subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        NSLog(@"Sign in result: %@", x);
    }];
```

Comment: The code is incorrect for this example.

So the map function in this sense doesn't behave in the way that, the map function for pull based streams behaves, that is it creates a new object and put's that new object into an array?

Rather the map function will 
1.pass in a signal(uibutton*) 
2.unwrap the from the signal (uibutton*)
3.allow a transformation of the ui button.

4a.in this case if we return a signal it will wrap the signal in a signal
5b.Resulting in a signal of signals

otherwise if it is a object type

4b. wrap object in signal
5b. resulting a signal

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Does the map function on a pull based stream behave differently from a map function based on push based streams ?

Comment: Also lets assume that, UIContorlEventTouchUpInside sends a next error, will self signInSignal run ?

Comment: Does map on pull vs push behave differently: Nope.

Comment: If the button's event signal sends an error, then no, signInSignal will not run.

Comment: Thanks alot ! this is clarified!